# Updating PHP Version in XAMPP on Windows 10 Without Losing Database: Seeking Optimal Solutions

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, version

I recently encountered an issue while initializing a new project using Composer. Upon running Composer, I received an error indicating a PHP version mismatch between the required version by my dependencies and the version installed on my system.

The error message from Composer reads:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies
> require a PHP version '>= 8.2.0'. You are running 8.1.2.

To resolve this, I've considered updating my PHP version. However, I'm hesitant to reinstall XAMPP due to concerns about preserving my database. I'm currently using Windows 10.

I researched how to update PHP on Windows 10 without reinstalling XAMPP to avoid losing the existing database. However, I was uncertain about the best method to achieve this while ensuring the integrity of my database.

Ultimately, I'm seeking guidance on the most effective approach to update the PHP version in my XAMPP environment on Windows 10 while preserving the database, as well as exploring alternative solutions to address the PHP version mismatch issue encountered with Composer.

What steps can I take to update my PHP version without reinstalling XAMPP, ensuring that my database remains intact? Additionally, is there a more optimal solution than the ones I've considered?

Comment: Simply export your mysql data first, then import it back after the change

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78226764/resolving-composer-dependency-error-due-to-php-version-mismatch? What have you tried to resolve it? Is this problem even related to Composer itself?

Comment: I would expand on what @KenLee suggested. I usually have multiple versions of xampp installed, with directories called `xampp-7.4`, `xampp-8.2`, etc. So, you could: 1) export / mysqldump the DB which you currently have, 2) install the newer version of Xampp with PHP version which you need, 3) visit `localhost/phpmyadmin` while the new Xampp is running, and 4) import your DB dump there. Then you would direct Composer to the PHP version you want to use, and let it do its thing.